# I don't know what 'straight' functions as, in "set someone straight"

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

> Don't worry, I set him straight on this matter.

I'd like to know what 'straight' functions as.
Does it function as being an adverb, or an adjective?

I don't know which is well fit to interpret the sentence correctly, because both seem to be fine for me to adjust to the sentence, regardless of whether it is an adverb or an adjective.

However thinking about the sentence, there seems not much difference in meaning whether it is used adverbly or adjectively.

A similar problem goes by 'right'

> They never get the facts right

In this case as well, regardless of how it is used, both seem to be interpreted perfectly.

However, on the whole, I think they might be used adjectively to complement the objects.

Answer (score 1):

**straight** there is an object complement.

Let's call it a **preposition** so that smoke does not start coming out of your ears as you ponder whether **straight** acts adverbially with respect to your action or with respect to its result, adjectivally.  I'd go with the latter.

Compare:

> I forwarded the request along.

Comment: By being set straight(used adverbly), he get to be straight(used adjectively) on this matter.  For this reason, I think 'straight' can be regarded as both an adverb and adjective at once as in "I set him straight on this matter". What do you think of my opinion?

Comment: I think it is both right and wrong.  How's that? :)

Comment: I would agree with you, though not sure as a non-native speaker. :)

Comment: When you set someone straight, you take some action that causes that person either to think or act correctly or properly.    *He thought they were not going to bid on the project but I set him straight*. You told him otherwise; you corrected his mistake.   *He has been acting out in class, but I set him straight*.  You may have punished him in some way to cause him to stop misbehaving, or you may have merely spoken with him.  Your action caused change in the person acted upon. They are now straight as a result of your straightening.  *I straightened him out*.

Comment: @EvaristeGalois I think it's best understood *internally* as an adjective with a "directional" sense of the sort ordinarily expressed with a locative preposition phrase, something like *on the right path*. *Externally* it is certainly an object complement, an adjectival describing *him*. It's not an adverbial--it doesn't modify *set*.

Comment: *He steered the boat straight.*